# Creating COM object in Threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, com

I have a button, behind that button i created a thread,

```
void FunctionCallingThreadFunction()
{
    AfxBeginThread(MyFunction, NULL);
}
```

In MyFunction i am creating a COM object, but when I create instance of it, null is returned to me,

```
MyFunction(LPVOID pvParam)
{
    comObject.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ClassName), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER);
}
```

But if i create this comObject in origional function it is created fine,

what is problem?,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `CoInitialize()` in every thread before attempting to create instances.

Comment: i have done CoInitialize(NULL); but now i am getting another exception "_com_error at memlory location 0x2321123..",

Comment: @fhnaseer you get this on the call to CreateInstance?

Comment: i debugged it, now i came to know that the error is "The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread", i think this is due to some complexity in my code,

Comment: @fhnaseer that seems to be a different issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call [CoInitializeEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909149.aspx) in each thread that uses COM.

Comment: i have done CoInitialize(NULL); but now i am getting another exception "_com_error at memlory location 0x2321123..",